# How to merge several csv file during a loop by joining columns on columns

Tags: pandas, csv, merge, iteration, multiple-columns

here 's my problem. I have 100 files, they all have two columns: 'time_slope' and 'slope'. I would like to create a single file with everything in it. Here is an example:

```
-----file 1----
2001.1     10
2001.2     20
2001.3     12
2001.4      4
2001.5      1
2001.6     13

-----file 2----
2001.3     20
2001.4     15
2001.5     6

-----file 3----
2001.6     15
2001.7     15
2001.8     15
2001.9     20
2002.0     23

**The expected result is:**
------- output file ---------
date    file1 file2 file3
2001.1    10   NAN  NAN
2001.2    20   NAN  NAN         
2001.3    12   NAN  NAN          
2001.4     4    15  NAN                     
2001.5     1     6  NAN                     
2001.6    13   NAN   15
2001.7   NAN   NAN   15
2001.8   NAN   NAN   15
2001.9   NAN   NAN   20
2002.0   NAN   NAN   23
```

**Here is what I tried:**

```
import pandas as pd
import os, glob
import numpy as np

filename_list = []

file_path = r"C:\Users\Path"
for file in glob.glob(path + "/*.csv"):
    filename_list.append(file)

from numpy import genfromtxt
df_ini = pd.read_csv('output.csv')         #IN FILE OUTPUT THERE ARE ALREADY TWO COLUMNS WITH VALUES
df_ini.columns=['time_slopes','slope']      
for filename in filename_list:
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    # convert numpy array into DataFrame
    numpyarray = genfromtxt(f, delimiter=',')
    df = pd.DataFrame({'time_slopes':numpyarray[:, 0],'slope':numpyarray[:, 1]})
    # remove NaN values:
    df = df.dropna(how='all')
    # re-index file:
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    # merge file:
    dfmerge = df_ini.merge(df,on='time_slopes',how='left')
    dfmerge.to_csv("output.csv", sep=',', index=False)
```

This piece of code return only two columns the first one (from df_ini) and the last one (from file number 100)...during each iteration the last column is rewrited instead of behind added.
date    file1 file100 
2001.1    10    NAN

Does anybody know how to solve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
file_1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': [2001.1, 2001.2, 2001.3], 'slope': [10, 20, 12]})
file_2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': [2001.4, 2001.5, 2001.6], 'slope': [20, 15, 6]})
file_3 = pd.DataFrame({'date': [2001.6, 2001.7, 2001.8], 'slope': [30, 40, 90]})

df_list = [file_1, file_2, file_3]
for df in df_list:
    df.index = df['date']
    df.drop(['date'], axis=1, inplace=True)

final_df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1, ignore_index=True)
final_df = final_df.reset_index()

print(final_df)
```

Output:

```
     date     0     1     2
0  2001.1  10.0   NaN   NaN
1  2001.2  20.0   NaN   NaN
2  2001.3  12.0   NaN   NaN
3  2001.4   NaN  20.0   NaN
4  2001.5   NaN  15.0   NaN
5  2001.6   NaN   6.0  30.0
6  2001.7   NaN   NaN  40.0
7  2001.8   NaN   NaN  90.0
```